# How to add custom methods with database logic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I created an application with this architecture:

- MyProject.**Model**: Contains POCO. Example:

> ```
> public class Car
> {
>      public int Id { get; set; }
>      public string Name { get; set; }
> }
> ```

- MyProject.**Repositories**: Contains repositories and UnitOfWork

> ```
> public class UnitOfWork
> {
>     // ...
>     public Repository<Car> Cars { get; set; }
>     // ...
> }
>
> public class Repository<T>
> {
>     // ...
>     // Add / Update / Delete ...
>     // ...
> }
> ```

- MyProject.**Web**: ASP.Net MVC application

Now I want to find a way to interact with data by using methods. For example in `MyProject.Model.Car` I want to add a method that will get data with non-navigation properties, a method named `GetSimilarCars()'. The problem is that the repository cannot interact with other repositories and thus cannot perform operations on the database.

I don't really know how to do this in a simple manner and what is the best place in my architecture to put this.

Another example could be `UserGroup.Deactivate()`, this method would deactivate each user and send them a notification by email. Of course I can put this method in the Web application Controller but I think this is no the place to put such code that could be called in many places in the application.

Note: I am using Entity Framework.

Any suggestion on how to implement such operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of stuff goes into your DAL (essentially your unit of work and repository, in this limited scenario). However, this is a pattern that bit me when I first starting working with MVC. Entity Framework *already* implements these patterns; your `DbContext` is your unit of work and your `DbSet` is your repository. All creating another layer on top of this does is add complexity. I personally ended up going with a service pattern instead, which merely sits on top of EF and allows me to do things like someService.GetAllFoo(). That way, the use of Entity Framework is abstracted away (I can switch out the DAL at any time. I can even remove the database completely and go with an API instead, without having to change any code in the rest of my application.) but I'm also not just reinventing the wheel.

In a service pattern, you're specifically only providing endpoints for the things you need, so it's a perfect candidate for things like `GetSimilarCars`, as you simply just add another method to the service to encapsulate the logic for that.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that your Business Layer (BL) would be communicating with your Data Access Layer (DAL). That way from your BL you could reach out to different repositories in DAL. That would solve your problem of repositories not being able to share data (that data would be shared through BL).

See here: [N-tier architecture w/ EF and MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70061/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-N-tier-En)

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite get you question but this is how you assign the values. And add it into a collection

```
public class Repository<T>
    {       

    List<car> _lstCar=new List<car>();
    //Add
    car cobj=new car();
    cobj.Id="1234";
    cobj.Name="Mercedes";

    _lstCar.Add(cobj);

    }
```

Comment: Yes, but how to get those values from the database? In each repository I don't have access to the UnitOfWork or other repositories

Comment: if it is SQL DB you have to add SQLconnection and execute a query to get the data you need.

Comment: if you have the DB added in your project. Create the object of the table and do the rest.